# Pre-load javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script to load the time and date, etc.  I have the result load into a div, and that div has an enter CSS3 animation.  The only problem is is that it takes a few seconds for the time and date to actually load and it just suddenly appears.  Since you don't see it immediately when you load the page, you don't even see the animation because it's over by the time the script loads.

So my question is: is it possible to delay the page load until after the time and date script has loaded?

Disclaimer: This is a purely experimental/creative project I'm working on so I'm not worried about efficiency.

Script:

```
    <script>
    var dayarray=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

    var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

    function getthedate(){
    var mydate=new Date()
    var year=mydate.getYear()
    if (year < 1000)
    year+=1900
    var day=mydate.getDay()
    var month=mydate.getMonth()
    var daym=mydate.getDate()
    if (daym<10)
    daym="0"+daym
    var hours=mydate.getHours()
    var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()
    var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()
    var dn="AM"
    if (hours>=12)
    dn="PM"
    if (hours>12){
    hours=hours-12
    }
    if (hours==0)
    hours=12
    if (minutes<=9)
    minutes="0"+minutes
    if (seconds<=9)
    seconds="0"+seconds
    //change font size here
    var cdate="<div class='ref'><span>"+hours+":"+minutes+"</span> "+dn+"</div>"+dayarray[day]+", "+montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year+""
    if (document.all)
    document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
    else if (document.getElementById)
    document.getElementById("time-date").innerHTML=cdate
    else
    document.write(cdate)
    }
    if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
    getthedate()
    function goforit(){
    if (document.all||document.getElementById)
    setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="goforit()">
   <div id="time-date"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code explicitly waits one second before loading the data. You should place an immediate call to `getthedate()` before the `setInterval()` statement:

```
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
    getthedate()
    setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
    }
```

This may obviate the need to block page loading. If this is not sufficient, you will want to place your code inline rather than calling it via `onload` which only runs after the entire page has been loaded.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the script from the `body onload` event, so by definition it will wait until the page has fully loaded.

If you wish the script to run earlier, you can place a script tag inside the HTML that calls the `goforit()` function at the position in parsing you wish, but the result may not be much better.

```
<div id="time-date"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  goforit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this script below your div.  Your div must load before it executes the script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
goforit();
</script>
```